# React Form Input onChange Test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, testing

I've been trying to solve this all day.  I've been all over the [Testing Library](https://testing-library.com/docs/) documentation and have tried many solutions.  The closest I could get is with the test code posted below.

**CreatePost.js**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

export default () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState('');
  const onSubmit = async event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/posts', {
      title
    });
    // clear title
    setTitle('');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={onSubmit} data-testid="form">
        <div className="form-group">
          <label htmlFor="titleInput">Title</label>
          <input
            data-testid="title"
            id="titleInput"
            type="text"
            name="title"
            placeholder="Title"
            value={title}
            onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            className="form-control"
          />
        </div>
        <button className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**CreatePost.test.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import CreatePost  from '../CreatePost';

it("Inputs should have the correct value", () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<CreatePost />)
  const input = getByLabelText(/title/i)
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..." } })

  expect(screen.getByRole(/title/i)).toHaveTextContent('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur....')
})
```

This is the only test I've tried that will fire the onChange event for the input as the console output shows that the value was updated.  However, my `expect` statement is not able to find the element. So why does it fire the onChange event, but cannot be found?

**Console Error**

```
FAIL  src/__test__/CreatePost.test.js
  ● Inputs should have the correct value

    TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an accessible element with the role "/title/i"

    Here are the accessible roles:

      textbox:

      Name "Title":
      <input
        class="form-control"
        data-testid="title"
        id="titleInput"
        name="title"
        placeholder="Title"
        type="text"
        value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..."
      />

      --------------------------------------------------
      button:

      Name "Submit":
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary"
      />

      --------------------------------------------------

    <body>
      <div>
        <div>
          <form
            data-testid="form"
          >
            <div
              class="form-group"
            >
              <label
                for="titleInput"
              >
                Title
              </label>
              <input
                class="form-control"
                data-testid="title"
                id="titleInput"
                name="title"
                placeholder="Title"
                type="text"
                value="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..."
              />
            </div>
            <button
              class="btn btn-primary"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </body>

       8 |   fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..." } })
       9 |
    > 10 |   expect(screen.getByRole(/title/i)).toHaveTextContent('Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur....')
         |                 ^
      11 | })
```

**I finally resolved my issue with the following Solution** 
I changed my input control to the following, removing some unused tags and adding the `aria-label` tag. (I think they are called tags or perhaps identifiers??)

```
<input
  type="text"
  aria-label="title" 
  placeholder="Title"
  value={title}
  onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
  className="form-control"
/>
```

**CreatePost.test.js**
It turns out I didn't need to use `screen`.

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent, cleanup } from '@testing-library/react';
import CreatePost  from '../CreatePost';

afterEach(cleanup)

it("Inputs should have the correct value", () => {
  const { getByLabelText } = render(<CreatePost />)
  const input = getByLabelText(/title/i)
  expect(input.value).toBe("");
  fireEvent.change(input, { target: { value: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur..." } })
  expect(input.value).toBe("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...");
})
```

Comment: May you add a role to the input?

Comment: After researching adding a role to the input, and looking at several examples, I was finally able to get the test passing. Also, It turned out that I did not need to use screen, but rather simply check the input.value.

Comment: Glad to hear that :D